# How to solve 'invalid address' using idSMTP

Tags: delphi, indy10

I've posted various questions trying to figure out all my issues with trying to send an email using TLS with Office365.

My last question here:  [How do I solve [EIdSMTPReplyError] Authentication unsuccessful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294984/how-do-i-solve-eidsmtpreplyerror-authentication-unsuccessful/60306003#60306003)

Since I couldn't solve the latter I got credentials of one of our clients and try testing the sample with their office credentials which brought me one step closer. With my own office credentials I'm just unable to authenticate (see previous link). In PowerShell there is no issue and I can send an email with the same credentials but not programmatically.

I'm now trying to figure out why the server is returning "Invalid Address" using the client's credentials.  Again, I'm able to use the exact same credentials in PowerShell and generate a sample email which works. But not with this component.

Slightly adjusted code from previous link:

```
procedure TForm28.SendEmail(poSMTP:TIdSMTP);
var
  loSMTPMessage   : TIdMessage;

begin
  loSMTPMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  with loSMTPMessage do
  begin
    Recipients.Add.Address := 'to address';
    ReplyTo.Add.Text  := edtUsername.Text;
    From.Address := edtUsername.Text;
    From.Name    := 'xxx';
    From.Text    := 'Test';
    Subject      := 'Test';
  end;
  poSMTP.Send(loSMTPMessage);
  loSMTPMessage.Free;
end;

procedure TForm28.Method2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  idSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
  idSASLLogin: TIdSASLLogin;
  idUserPassProvider: TIdUserPassProvider;
  lp:PWideChar;
  liSize:Cardinal;

begin
  idSMTP1 := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  idSMTP1.OnFailedRecipient := IdSMTP1FailedRecipient;

   //have tried all these variations in trying to solve authentication issue

//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNameNetBIOS);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNameDnsHostname);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNameDnsDomain);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified);
//  IdSMTP1.HeloName := GetComputerNameExString(ComputerNameMax);  

  try
    idSMTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idSMTP1);
    idSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(idSMTP1.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];

    idSMTP1.Host := edtSMTP.Text;
    idSMTP1.Port := StrToInt(cbPort.Text);

    idSASLLogin := TIdSASLLogin.Create(idSMTP1);
    idUserPassProvider := TIdUserPassProvider.Create(idSASLLogin);

    idSASLLogin.UserPassProvider := idUserPassProvider;
    idUserPassProvider.Username := edtUsername.Text;
    idUserPassProvider.Password := edtPassword.Text;

    idSMTP1.AuthType := satSASL;
    idSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := idSASLLogin;

    try
      idSMTP1.Connect;
      try
        if idSMTP1.Authenticate then
          SendEmail(idSMTP1);
      finally
        idSMTP1.Disconnect;
      end;
      ShowMessage('OK');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage(Format('Failed!'#13'[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    idSMTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This gives me an error: Project SMTP_SSL_Example.exe raised exception class EIdSMTPReplyError with message 'Invalid address
'.

Comment: please provide the code for SendEmail and what is the value of cbport, edtSMTP.Text? Please make a complete example.

Comment: stupid question maybe but is the sender email address the same as the login you use? If not, this wont work...

Comment: Ok, I've added the send.  yes, the username and sender is identical

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gosh.

```
From.Text    := 'Test';
```

called after

```
From.Address := edtUsername.Text
```

was changing my email address to 'test'.
Cannot believe I've wasted time with something stupid like this.

Comment: well glad you found it, next time include all details in the question ;)

Comment: `TIdMessage.From` is a `TIdEMailAddressItem`, setting its `Text` property sets its `Name` and `Address` properties, and `'Test'` is not a valid email address. You probably meant to set `From.Name` instead of setting `From.Text`.